# Compiling java file that has Multiple classes

Tags: java

I have the following one file that contains two classes, A, and B which extends A. But I am confused on how to compile and what to name the file.
I thought I should name it B.java since that main function runs B but it tells me that it can't find the main function.

```
    import static java.lang.System.out; 

class A {
    protected int x = 0xF0;
    protected int z; 
    public A(){
        z = fun(x);
        out.printf ("%x ", z);
    }

public int fun(int i) { return (i + 1); }
public static int staticFun (int i) { return (i + 3);}
}

class B extends A {
    protected int y = 0x11;
    public B() { 
        z = fun( z);
        out.printf ("%x ",z); 
}

public int fun(int i) { return (i + 2);}
public static int staticFun(int i) {return (i + 4);}

public static void main(String args[]){
    int i = 0;
    A a = new B();
    out.print ( a.fun( i)+ " ");
    out.println( a.staticFun(i));
    B b = new B();
    out.print ( b.fun (i) + " ");
    out.println( b.staticFun(i));
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make at least one of the classes `public`, and name file as public class.
Assuming you make `class A` public, compiling file using `javac A.java` will create two class files - `A.class` and `B.class`. Executing `B.class` with command `java B` will result executing `main` method from `class B`.